# Extract epoch from moment object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to extract the unix timestamp (epoch) from a date string as follows:

`var week        = $("#week").val();
var timestamp   = moment(week).format("X");
console.log(timestamp);`

This returns, in the console `"Invalid Date"`.

I am passing the following format: `"03-Nov-16"`

I am trying to return the unix timestamp of a date.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell moment the format of the date string you're trying to parse. I think you're looking for something like this (not tested):

`var timestamp = moment("03-Nov-16", "DD-MMM-YY").unix()`

See the [official docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) on date string parsing for more info.

Comment: @WalkerFarrow Glad I could help! You should mark this as the correct answer by clicking the check mark above so others users are aware. Thanks!